# It's 2020. Is there any way to get syslog to work on macOS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, macos

Questions on syslog on macOS get no answers these days, the reason apparently being that 'it just doesn't work'.

Still, I would like to try one more time.

Is there a way that a syslog opened with

```
openlog ('apns', 'ndelay', 'mail');
```

to work on macOS Mojave?

Comment: Linking to related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256769/how-to-use-logger-command-on-sierra and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13888/why-is-syslog-not-logging-where-i-tell-it-to-log to help connect informative, if old, `syslog` and `logger` questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, the old way of logging is gone. The API to write to the new unified log are published.

- https://eclecticlight.co/2018/03/19/macos-unified-log-1-why-what-and-how/
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging

There are quite a few WWDC sessions covering this as well as hundreds of blog posts with specifics. Depending on what specifically you are trying to do, the unified log can be a quick patch and sometimes be much better than when each log went to a different file.

To address your specific code, you would create an object instead of calling openlog function.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code

Then it’s pretty equivalent to inject your values into the system logging stream. From the command line shell, you can still call `logger` and nothing has changed. How you compile or interpret your code will govern which API you call, but it’s totally allowed to log still in 2020 on macOS.